How to show passwords stored as MD5() in Mysql as non-compliant?
How can I show which MD5()-encrypted passwords are not compliant with current password standards when MD5() is a one-way hash?
Ideally, I might have a Mysql function that decrypts the MD5 and then I can confirm if the plain text password conforms to current password standards.

You can't, not without brute-forcing the hashes. That's the point of the hash function being one-way.

As you wrote, MD5 is a one-way hash function. You cannot decrypt it as there is no encrypted text. You would need a rainbow table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to check. However, if the password is hashed using a salt, then the rainbow table will be useless.

Don't use MD5 for passwords at all to begin with.

In a properly built system the only points at which the plain text password is accesible is when the user changes his password or when the user logins correctly. In both cases, you see the password before hashing, and at that point you can validate it. But the stored hash is impossible to reverse, other than brute forcing it.

The industry stopped using md5 because it doesn't have collision resistance which is one of the qualities a 'cryptographic' hash function needs to have. It doesn't really affect its usefulness for hashing passwords compared with other fast collision resistant algorithms like sha256 however. Using fast hashes for password hashing does increase the length of passwords needed for equivalent security though, compared to slow hashes like bcrypt. There are no known feasible first or second pre-image attacks on md5.

@SimonGoater, There are valid uses for MD5, just not for password hashing. NIST never adopted MD5 as a recommended algorithm for passwords, so they had no policy to stop.

@BillKarwin I didn't say anything about NIST. If there's anything factually incorrect with my comment, please let me know.

"The industry stopped using md5" is incorrect.

I of course meant in the context of password hashing.

It's incorrect even in the context of password hashing, because MD5 was never adopted as a valid password hashing algorithm.

Anyway, the solution to "how do I force users who have non-compliant passwords to change them" is to do that in the login phase when you do have that plaintext in hand. If the login would otherwise succeed, but the plaintext password is non-compliant, you'd flag it, or force the user to change it then and there.

An additional refinement is to expire passwords that haven't been used in say, 12 months, as presumptively non-compliant when you are changing password hashing algorithms.
